# Ember.js save() after createRecord sends empty req.body to my express.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ember.js

When I use createRecord and then save, the express server receives the post request but the req.body is empty. I made the same post request using Postman and it works perfectly. The get request works too in the tasks template displaying the tasks in a list.

This is my ember code:

Route (tasks.js):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('task');
  },
  actions: {
   addTask() {
     const task = this.store.createRecord('task', {
       title: this.get("controller.title")
     });

     task.save();

   }
 }
});
```

Model (task.js):

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import DS from 'ember-data';


export default Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Template (tasks.hbs):

```
{{input value=title}}
<button id="add-task" {{action "addTask"}}>Add</button>

<br><br>

{{#each model as |task|}}
    {{task.title}}<br>
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

I'm using the default ember JSONAPIAdapter.

Comment: When you made the request with Postman, did you set the MIME type to jsonapi like Ember does? Might that be it, express not understanding it? I know I have to configure Ruby on Rails or I get a blank body as well.

Comment: try using chrome console and comparing requests (urls, headers, form data, etc) ... also please check that this.get("controller.title") is really working.

Answer (score 7):

Ember and JSONAPIAdapter is sending the header with type application/vnd.api+json. I got it working by adding this in express.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
```

Comment: Thanks! saved my time. Didn't want to use AJAX request in Controller, although it was working.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue using JSONAPIAdapter. It seems there is some mismatch in headers. I haven't figured out what is wrong.

But I got it working by using the RESTAdapter instead.